# is there anyway to change easly Interface Orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface, orientation

I have MainWindow.xib file and I try to desing a second .xib file which is MainWindowLandscape.xib. I have many .xib file and I design them separately for Portrait and Landscape.

I want to assign them in MainWindow.xib and MainWindowLandscape.xib ( UITabbarController based ), I mean I will assign portrait views in MainWindow.xib, and landscape views in MainWindowLandscape.xib. Is it possible or what is the easiest way?

All views ( portrait and landscape ) do same thing in each other. Only UI will be change.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by overriding

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

in the view controllers associated to the two xib files.

Concretely, in case you want to force the orientation to always be portrait, do:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation      {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
       return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

When you want to force your view controller to always show in landscape:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation      { 
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
       return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Once you do this, you have to keep in mind that controllers will auto rotate only if they meet the conditions for it to happen. Specifically, for tab bar controllers, *all* internal controllers must support the given orientation (i.e., they should implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` like above).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're suggesting, but the documentation states that the result of `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` should *not* change dynamically.

Comment: @jtbandes: it seems to me that my `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` implementations are pretty static. Each implementation is specific to a controller type, if it was not clear...

Comment: Ah ok. I just misinterpreted "when you want to force landscape".

Comment: yes I have added this block to my project all views but it doesn't work ? is there any tutorial that you know which has UITabbarController and UINavigationController?

Comment: Don't know of any tutorial, but have a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868132/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-wont-work -- if you need more help, you could post some code...