# UIView not rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, interface-orientation

I have a UIViewController with UIWebView, Navigation bar and bottom tool bar.
I am trying to rotate it to support interface orientation changes. But it is not working.

I have returned YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, but still not working.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Does shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation get called? If not, it could be that the UIViewController isn't actually active.

Comment: is there a tabbarcontroller involved?

Comment: No tabbar, a tool bar at the bottom to control events of webview

Comment: In the Info.plist for the app, are all the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations "supported interface orientations" that you want to support listed?

Comment: Yes listed in plist file as well

Comment: How about if you try some of the answers posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868132/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-doesnt-work

Comment: Probably you need to add rotation support to UINavigationController, not to UIViewController.