# GameCenter landscape orientation doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, game-center

Can anyone explain me what's going on? I use this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:( UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {     
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
 }
```

to provide landscape orientation for the matchmakerViewController. It works perfectly on iPhone and even on iPad simulator but not on iPad device. When i run the application on iPad matchmakerViewController misteriously appear in the portrait orientation. What's wrong? How do i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` like

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:( UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {     
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
 }
```

Also check your application plist file, there will be a **key** like **Supported Interface Orientations** it's type will be array and will have **4 values**. **Delete the portrait modes from the plist and save it**.
It will work. Please check this.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: did you check parent view controller's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method ? Is it same as return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); ?

Comment: i did. it's different. if i make it return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); it starts displaying in portrait mode

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: is your full application is working on landscape mode or only this view is set to landscape ?

Comment: all the application is landscape

Comment: Please return 'NO' from the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method. And check is the view rotates.

Also add the [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; in your application delegates applicationDidFinishLoading Method. Check and update I'll help you.

Comment: Also check that your matchmakerViewController is a subclass of UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

(This is most likely not your problem, but I use the following code and it works fine)

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
```

Additionally, make sure the parent view is set to autorotate true. [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868132/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the elegant solution through Categories, extend the GKMatchMakerViewController, the same solution will work on any other game center view such as leader board views and achievement views:

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GameKit/GameKit.h"

@interface GKMatchmakerViewController(LandscapeOnly)



-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "GKMatchmakerViewController-Landscape.h"

@implementation GKMatchmakerViewController(LandscapeOnly)


-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);


}

@end
```

Let me know if it works!!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}


also check parent controller maybe some controller return YES

or try 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    else 
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: or try exchange (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) to
(interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)